# why my CSS file is not loading?

Tags: css, codeigniter-2

I am using following code to load my css file in my codeigniter website.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php $base_url?><?php $css?>style.css" />
```

In my `config.php` I have used this code.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite';
$config['css']  = "/assets/css/";
```

But css is not loading.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?><?php echo $css; ?>style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I toiled for many days to connect my html to CSS. Eventually, I discovered that the quotation marks of the other tags in the html  tag were all written incorrectly. This prevented my CSS from loading despite the HTML working well.

Try rewriting them with the correct quotation marks, e.g., ensure

```
href="styles.css"
```

instead of

```
href=”styles.css”
```

and etc.

Good luck.